# How do I change the value of a cell based on the day

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-finance

I need to change the formula in a google sheets cell depending on whether it is a Monday or not.

If it is Monday, `=min(GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", Today()-3))` works fine as `Today()-3` is a FRIDAY(last trading day).

However if it is any other day, i need to use, `=min(GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", Today()-1))` to show the PREVIOUS day's low.

is there an if statement that works for this? I think i get the structure,

`=if (day == Monday), =min(GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", Today()-3), =min(GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", Today()-1))`

but i'm not sure about the `day == monday` part.

Comment: weekday(day)==2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) support the [WORKDAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) function. This allows you to specify a day that disregards weekends and optionally, a holiday list.

```
=GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", workday(today(), -1))
```

I'm unclear on what MIN() is intended to accomplish. Perhaps something like,

```
=min(GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", workday(today(), -1)), GoogleFinance(A2, "LOW", workday(today(), -2)))
```

For non-standard weekends, both platforms support [WORKDAY.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d) which allows you to specify non-working days.

My personal recommendation is a fully expanded WORKDAY.INTL function that references a holiday list for your particular exchange.

Comment: Hope this passed your 'test' for intelligence! <pun intended>

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.